# Powershell : build dynamic invoke-command for SSL and NOSSL connections

Tags: powershell

We have servers that are setup with type type of WinRM connection Secure and normal.

I need to establish a remote powershell connection with or without the -usessl switch.

I wanted to avoid having two identical script blocks with the only difference being having or not having the -usessl switch.

I tried using argument splatting but can't deal with the **-usessl switch**, also tried using invoke-expression but that broke the ability to retrieve data; Hash value from the remote job.

Any suggestions ?

```
if (test-wsman -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -cn "$($Cmpname.name).sample.com" –UseSSL ) {
Write-host $Cmpname.name,WSMan Connected SSL 
$strWSMAN = "SSL"
$strRemoteHash = invoke-command -cn "$($Cmpname.name).sample.com" -usessl  -scriptblock {
        Write-host "calculating Hash values"
        $strLocalhash = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\Windows\ccmcache" -Filter "Windows10.0-KB4041691-x64.cab" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | Get-FileHash -Algorithm sha1

    New-Object pscustomobject -Property @{
    RemotePath = $strLocalhash.path 
    RemoteHash = $strLocalhash.hash 
    }
    }

}  else {   
    $strWSMAN = "NoSSL"
    $strRemoteHash = invoke-command -cn "$($Cmpname.name).sample.com" -scriptblock {
    Write-host "calculating Hash values"
    $strLocalhash = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\Windows\ccmcache" -Filter "Windows10.0-KB4041691-x64.cab" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | Get-FileHash -Algorithm sha1

    New-Object pscustomobject -Property @{
    RemotePath = $strLocalhash.path 
    RemoteHash = $strLocalhash.hash 
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: -UseSSL is a switch parameter.  You can use splatting with those by using $true or $false as the parameter value, according to whether you want it enabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

As [mjolinor said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731974/powershell-build-dynamic-invoke-command-for-ssl-and-nossl-connections#comment80410656_46731974), you need to provide a boolean value for a switch parameter when splatting:

```
$ParameterValues = @{
    ComputerName = "$($Cmpname.name).sample.com"
    UseSSL = [bool](Test-WSMan -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ComputerName "$($Cmpname.name).sample.com" –UseSSL)
    ScriptBlock = {
        Write-host "calculating Hash values"
        $strLocalhash = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\Windows\ccmcache" -Filter "Windows10.0-KB4041691-x64.cab" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | Get-FileHash -Algorithm sha1

        New-Object pscustomobject -Property @{
            RemotePath = $strLocalhash.path 
            RemoteHash = $strLocalhash.hash 
        }
    }
}
Invoke-Command @ParameterValues
```